# spark-submit: Difference between " --master local[n]" and "--master local --executor-cores m"

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark

I have a dual-core machine (with 2 threads on each core). I run a Spark job with 2 different `spark-submit` parameters.

```
spark-submit --master local[4]

spark-submit --master local --executor-cores 2
```

Is there really any difference between the two examples above? I am trying to get Spark to use 4 total threads for Spark "tasks", 2 threads on each physical core.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all `--executor-cores` argument or `spark.executor.cores` configuration option are not applicable in local mode. As a result:

- `--master local[4]` starts Spark in the local mode using four worker threads.
- `--master local` starts Spark in the local mode using one worker thread. `--executor-core` has no effect.

This accounts only for "data processing" threads. Overall number of threads used by Spark can be significantly larger.

Without going into OS and scheduling details the first option is the one you're looking for if you want to utilize four threads.