# Parallelize in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am very new to Spark and the codes I have developed arent working as fast as I was expecting them to. I am initiating the spark context in the following way

## Initialize Spark Environment

```py
spark_path = "C:\spark"
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = spark_path
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME'] = spark_path

sys.path.append(spark_path + "/bin")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/pyspark/")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib/pyspark.zip")
sys.path.append(spark_path + "/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip")

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

sc = SparkContext("local", "test")
```

Now I decided to check the degree of parallelism this is acheiving and used

```
sc.defaultParallelism
>>> 1
```

My question is three fold

1. Am I acheiving no parallelism?
2. If not then how can I?
3. I need to put I specific setting for my work which I have been told. The setting is  `--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 --conf spark.akka.frameSize=128`. How can I go about setting this

I am working on a windows server with 4 cores and 30gb RAM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spark-submit: Difference between " --master local\[n\]" and "--master local --executor-cores m"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939076/spark-submit-difference-between-master-localn-and-master-local-exec)

Answer (score 0):

when creating context, try `sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "test")` to utilize all the available cores